# Image is getting outside of div IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to use grid layout but it wasn't working as expected in IE11, and i've observed that images is getting outside to the maximum width of the container in IE for remaining browsers i see it fine. do i missing anything in my code.

here is my code,

```css
//trying to workout grid in ie using this query

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {

.grid_container{
   display: -ms-grid;
  //  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1.5rem 1fr 1.5rem 1fr;
   background-color: red;
   max-width: 1100px;
   width: 65%;
   margin: 10px auto;
}

.grid_container > div:nth-of-type(1){
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row:1; 
}

.grid_container> div:nth-of-type(2){
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
}
.grid_container> div:nth-of-type(3){
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 3;
}
.grid_container> div:nth-of-type(4){
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
}
.grid_container> div:nth-of-type(5){
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
}


.box-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.box-item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.box-text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
}


}
```

```html
<div class="grid_container">
 <div class="box-item">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/255/200/200.jpg?hmac=IYQV36UT5-F1dbK_CQXF7PDfLfwcnwKijqeBCo3yMlc" />
  <div class="box-text">
   dummy text
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box-item">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/255/200/200.jpg?hmac=IYQV36UT5-F1dbK_CQXF7PDfLfwcnwKijqeBCo3yMlc" />
  <div class="box-text">
   dummy text
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box-item">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/255/200/200.jpg?hmac=IYQV36UT5-F1dbK_CQXF7PDfLfwcnwKijqeBCo3yMlc" />
  <div class="box-text">
   dummy text
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box-item">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/255/200/200.jpg?hmac=IYQV36UT5-F1dbK_CQXF7PDfLfwcnwKijqeBCo3yMlc" />
  <div class="box-text">
   dummy text
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box-item">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/255/200/200.jpg?hmac=IYQV36UT5-F1dbK_CQXF7PDfLfwcnwKijqeBCo3yMlc" />
  <div class="box-text">
   dummy text
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow no longer supports I.E, so your IE 11 specific question doesn't display correctly, and the code example that you supplied can't be run in Stackoverflow.  Put your code in one of the online code demo tool, but make sure that it support IE 11, but not codpen.io or jsfiddle which also doesn't work with IE 11. :(

Comment: I copied your code to a local file on my computer and ran it the latest version of IE, before it was abandoned by MicroSoft, and it only showed the first two pictures with the titles placed on the extreme right of each picture.  Then I added overflow: auto to the container's first css rule, and all of the pictures showed, but not scrolled.  I hope that this is helpful.. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @HowardBrown, thanks for the reply may i know where you have applied the overflow is it for .grid-container

Comment: Hi @HowardBrown, my intention is to fit all the top3 images within redbackground not to exceed that.

Comment: When I try to run the sample code in IE 11 I got [this result](https://imgur.com/a/Tc0pYU5). You can notice that images are within a container. Do you mean when you resize the browser window, gird and images should be adjusted according to the width? If possible try to provide detailed information about it and try to provide the snapshot of the issue in IE 11 and provide the picture of the desired output. It can really help us to understand the issue and your requirements. We can try to provide further suggestions based on it. Thanks for your understanding.